# How to deal with tax in website order with multi company products?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

This question is about how to deal with tax in website order with multi company products in odoo 11. Please take below scenario:

Lets assume there are 3 companies C1, C2, C3. C2 and C3 are child companies of C1.

Lets assume there is 18% tax available in C1, C2 and C3.

C1 adds C2 and C3 tax while creating the product.

C2 and C3 publish their products with tax in the C1 website. Customer purchases C2 products from website. Tax is applied for the product and C1 is able to see the tax in the order.

But C2 is not able to see the tax in the order/quotation table, but tax has been calculated with the total.

Same for C3 products purchased from website.

Please help me with this, I need a solution to apply different company tax for that company product and that company needs to see that too.

Comment: Please add your setup and what you have tried so far to your question.

Comment: @KlausD. I have created 3 companies, each company has products with tax and are published on the website. When customer places the order, tax is applied to the product but it is taking the parent company tax, hence I am not able to see the tax from the child company admin view. I want to see the tax from the child company.

Comment: It might habe been great if your would have name what software you are doing it on. You just placed a tag.

Comment: @KlausD. Sure updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

please check in your user have access like blow screenshot.

[image]

This two option one of option is selected then after user can see tax if this is ticked then see in your tax configuration.

[image]

Thanks